# Como pegar o valor de uma Variável associada a um Checkbutton no Tkinter? - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Como eu poderia pegar o valor contido em checkBtVar tendo como referencia ckBt?

```
for x in range(10):
  checkBtVar = Variable()

  ckBt = Checkbutton(root, variable=checkBtVar)
  ckBt.bind("<Button-1>",click)
  ckBt.pack()

def click(event):
  widget = event.widget
  v = widget.get()
  if v == True:
    #faça algo
```

Existiria algo do tipo **"var.get()" ?**

*(Obs: O código acima é só para Exemplificar)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desconheço algo do tipo **"var.get()"**, porém você pode pegar o builtin `__dict__` e pegar o conteúdo da chave `_tclCommands`. Para este exemplo funciona.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def click(event):
  print(event.widget.__dict__.get("_tclCommands", "Nenhum valor dentro de _tclCommands"))
  

for x in range(10):
  checkBtVar = Variable()
  ckBt = Checkbutton(root, variable=checkBtVar)
  ckBt.bind("<Button-1>",click)
  ckBt.pack()
```

**UPDATE**

Baseado no update de seu post, acho que isso te ajudará:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()  

opt = []
ckButtons = []
ckButtons_v = []

def checkbox_clicked():
    for i, item in enumerate(ckButtons):
        opt[i]=(ckButtons_v[i].get())
    print(opt)


for x in range(10):
    ckButtons_v.append(Variable())
    off_value = False
    ckButtons.append(Checkbutton(root, onvalue=True, offvalue=off_value, variable=ckButtons_v[x], command=checkbox_clicked))
    opt.append(off_value)
    ckButtons[-1].deselect()
    ckButtons[-1].pack()
```

Cada vez que um checkButton for clicado, você terá algo como:

> [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Onde 1 é o botão marcado e 0 desmarcado.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Paulo, como eu poderia fazer uma comparação usando esse método? Eu queria o valor da variável para saber se o CheckButton estava selecionado ou não. tipo: if widget.checkBtVar == True: >>   (Obs: Corrigi o exemplo do código para que ficasse mais clara a minha duvida)